# Android music player counter service

Tags: android

I want to write an application that monitors a music player. In my app I want to start a service, that listens to some media player (best case: any media player; worst case: a specific media player), to get the 10 most listened audio tracks' titles and authors. Is this possible? I searched the web for hours, but I found nothing relevant.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a music player that writes to the log some information that I need. Did anyone use such a media player?

Comment: Did you check for the player's broadcasts? Check the public API (the music player's manifest) for any relevant broadcasts/intents/service binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Not really. There might be some music players that broadcast this information that you could track, but I do not know of any, and that'd be a privacy issue if they did.